# How to use Liquify for Liquibase

Tags: sql, type-conversion, liquibase

I'm studiyng Liquibase and I'd like to use Liquify for testing xml/sql conversion, but i can't understand how to get liquify.jar and how to use it.

Comment: Have you tried building from source and use as described in documentation here: https://github.com/daquino/liquify ?

Comment: yes, but it responds with "no main manifest attribute in liquify.jar". I just used Gradle for building, obviously

Answer (score 0):

I compiled with

```
gradlew dist
```

and liquify.jar appeared with right manifest attributes. I can't understand why it didn't appears with precedent compilings.... that's all.